# Conditionally summing numbers in file from jq with awk

Tags: bash, awk

**EDIT: While typing this out/explaining it to myself, I found the problem. Posting at this point for reference.**

I have a JSON file containing some k8s compute resource requirements, and I'm trying to sum up the requests and limits separately.

```
$ jq -r '.resources.requests.memory' qauat_resources.json
4Gi
4Gi
4Gi
4Gi
4Gi
4Gi
4Gi
4Gi
4Gi
4Gi
4Gi
4Gi
4Gi
4Gi
4Gi
```

```
$ jq -r '.resources.limits.memory' qauat_resources.json
5153960755200m
5153960755200m
5153960755200m
5153960755200m
5153960755200m
5153960755200m
10307921510400m
10307921510400m
10307921510400m
10307921510400m
10307921510400m
10307921510400m
10307921510400m
10307921510400m
10307921510400m
```

This works to sum up the first block:

```
$ jq -r '.resources.requests.memory' qauat_resources.json | awk '{s+=$1; unit=" GiB"} END {print s unit}'
60 GiB
```

The latter ones are outputted in millibytes (no idea why, [related Github issue)](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/74986), piping it to this works just fine (converts to GiB):

```
$ awk '{s+=$1 / (1.074*10^12); unit=" GiB"} END {print s unit}'
115.172 GiB
```

My concern is that the issue may get fixed, and/or an output will include mixed GiB/mB in it, so I wanted to do this:

```
$ awk '{s>10^5 ? s+=$1/(1.074*10^12) : s+=$1; unit=" GiB"} END {print s unit}'
```

Basically, if it's an absurdly large number (for memory requirements in GiB), assume it's been outputted as mB and convert it, otherwise just add it. If I run the second block through it (less END), I get this.

```
$ jq -r '.resources.limits.memory' qauat_resources.json \
  | awk '{s>10^5 ? s+=$1/(1.074*10^12) : s+=$1; unit=" GiB"} {print s unit}'
5153960755200 GiB
5.15396e+12 GiB
5.15396e+12 GiB
5.15396e+12 GiB
5.15396e+12 GiB
5.15396e+12 GiB
5.15396e+12 GiB
5.15396e+12 GiB
5.15396e+12 GiB
5.15396e+12 GiB
5.15396e+12 GiB
5.15396e+12 GiB
5.15396e+12 GiB
5.15396e+12 GiB
5.15396e+12 GiB
```

So it's not adding, and is formatting everything after the first output. This, to me, would indicate that the ternary is going to the 2nd statement, except that uses the += operator. Also, if I invert the logic (<, not >), it sums as expected. Given that the smallest number in there is assuredly greater than 10^5 (5153960755200 > 10^5), I assumed that awk isn't treating it as an int, so I forced it with s+0, but it had the same output. Even more bizarrely, if I change the conditional to s==0, the first line is a correct conversion to GiB, every line after that is falling to the 2nd statement. I thus assume that the first output is seen as equal to 0, but once it's been added to, it is no longer the case.

I'm using GNU Awk 5.0.1 in zsh on a Mac, and while I'm open to using other tools, at this point it's an intellectual curiosity. It's also entirely possible I'm just missing something really obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was simply that s is initialized to 0, so the first comparison is always going to be < 10^5 (or any other natural number, for that matter), but immediately after, it'll be true, so the ternary will switch statements. I shouldn't have been checking s, but rather $1 as a comparison. Also note that you do have to cast it using +0. Finally, I tested this on both gawk and MacOS-style nawk; it works for both.

```
awk '{$1+0 > 10^5 ? s+=$1/(1.074*10^12) : s+=$1; unit=" GiB"} {print s unit}'
```

Comment: I think `jq` can do arithmetic and conditions.

Comment: You are correct, there are many ways to accomplish this. I think you can also use paste to sum up numbers in a file, albeit without the other math functions.